# Pass Name and Value of Character Vector into Function using lapply

Tags: r

I have a function that takes two arguments:

```
my.function <- function(name, value) {

  print(name)

  print(value) #using print as example

}
```

I have an integer vector that has names and values:

```
  freq.chars <- table(sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace=TRUE))
```

I'd like to use lapply to apply my.function to freq.chars where the name of each item is passed in as x, and the value (in this case frequency) is passed in as y.

When I try,

```
lapply(names(freq.chars), my.function)
```

I get an error that "value" is missing with no default.

I've also tried

```
 lapply(names(freq.chars), my.function, name = names(freq.chars), value = freq.chars)
```

, in which case I get an error: unused argument value = c(...).

Sorry for the edits and clarity, I'm new at this...

Comment: This is too broad, please provide a reproducible example and show us what you've tried and what exactly isn't working.

Answer (score 4):

We use this test data:

```
set.seed(123) # needed for reproducibility
char.vector <- sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace=TRUE)
freq.chars <- table(char.vector)
```

Here are several variations:

```
# 1. iterate simultaneously over names and values
mapply(my.function, names(freq.chars), unname(freq.chars))

# 2. same code except Map replaces mapply.  Map returns a list.
Map(my.function, names(freq.chars), unname(freq.chars))

# 3. iterate over index and then turn index into names and values
sapply(seq_along(freq.chars), 
  function(i) my.function(names(freq.chars)[i], unname(freq.chars)[i]))

# 4. same code as last one except lapply replaces sapply.  Returns list.
lapply(seq_along(freq.chars), 
  function(i) my.function(names(freq.chars)[i], unname(freq.chars)[i]))

# 5. this iterates over names rather than over an index
sapply(names(freq.chars), function(nm) my.function(nm, freq.chars[[nm]]))

# 6. same code as last one except lapply replaces sapply.  Returns list.
lapply(names(freq.chars), function(nm) my.function(nm, freq.chars[[nm]]))
```

Note that `mapply` and `sapply` have an optional `USE.NAMES` argument that controls whether names are inferred for the result and an optional `simplify` argument ('SIMPLIFY`for`mapply`) which controls whether list output is simplified.  Use these arguments for further control.

**Update** Completely revised presentation.

Comment: This is close, but I get the following error: Error: unexpected symbol in "lapply(seq_along(x), my.function(i) fun"

Comment: I have modified the answer now that there is some code in the question.

Comment: Egad! That does it. Coming from a Python background, this is surprisingly confusing. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add another parameter to your function, specify it after the function name (3rd parm in lapply).

```
lapply(names(freq.chars), my.function, char.vector)
```